# SSH alias results in SSH usage instructions

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I have the following alias in my .bash_profile file:

alias rlogin="ssh -l elykl33t rlogin.server"

Of course this is not the actual username or server address.

When I, after relaunching terminal, type "rlogin" I am met with:

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

If I run the command `source .bash_profile` then the command works fine. Am I doing something wrong? Is this type of command just not possible the way I'm doing it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: In a new terminal, what does `type -a rlogin` tell you? It sounds like a new terminal does not give you a login shell, so if you log out and log in you'll be fine.

Comment: It says 'rlogin is /usr/bin/rlogin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that output too when I type `/usr/bin/rlogin` with no arguments. My system has this set of symbolic links:

```
/usr/bin/rlogin -> /etc/alternatives/rlogin
/etc/alternatives/rlogin -> /usr/bin/slogin
/usr/bin/slogin -> ssh
```

So when you call rlogin, you are calling ssh already.

Your terminals do not launch a login shell, so the changes to .bash_profile do not get seen. Either:

1. log out and log back in.
2. move your alias to .bashrc